# Blazor Web Assembly Imput Form Model, binding complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, input, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Please help me with advice. I am making BLAZOR Web Assembly App C# Input Form, a module consists of two modules:

```
public class CLASS1
{
    public MOD1 User { get; set; }
    public MOD2 CLient { get; set; }
}

public class MOD1
{
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class MOD2
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use this complex module in the input form?

```
<EditForm Model="CLASS1" OnSubmit="Creat" class="form-body"\>
     <h1 class="text-center"\>Create new user\</h1\>
     <div class="form-group"\> \<label\>Name\*\</label\>
          <InputText id="firstName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="CLASS1.MOD2.Name???????????????????????" /\>
     </div\> ...
</EditForm\>
```

I don't have any idea(((.

Comment: do you have any update on this question?

Comment: Hello, Tiny, maybe you can tell me how i can save my data from Form in Data Base. How i can call controller in Page. razor?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm afraid you are concerning how to save data into a database, and I think this [high voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996775) already have a good sample. In short, you are having a blazor wsam app so we still need an API(maybe you can have an asp.net core hosted backend app as the API, or just create a seperate api project), then in the API project, using ef core to connect to your database and provide CRUD actions, the next you need to do is collecting the form data in the onsubmit function in Page.razor and call the API to pass the data to controller.

Answer (score 0):

EditForm is used for having a form in blazor page, we have [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0) here to show us how to use `EditForm`.

I have codes below with a simple test, could you pls take a look at it?

```
<EditForm Model="@MyModel" OnSubmit="@FormSubmit">
    <div>
        Email:<InputText @bind-Value="MyModel!.User.Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        phone number:<InputText @bind-Value="MyModel!.User.PhoneNumber" />
    </div>
    <div>
        client name:<InputText @bind-Value="MyModel!.CLient.Name" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    public CLASS1? MyModel { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MyModel = new CLASS1
        {
            User = new MOD1(),
                CLient = new MOD2()
        };
    } 

    private void FormSubmit()
    {
        var res = MyModel.User.PhoneNumber;
    }

    public class CLASS1
    {
        public MOD1 User { get; set; }
        public MOD2 CLient { get; set; }
    }

    public class MOD1
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class MOD2
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have hier other problems.

Comment: maybe you can create a new question